# Does statement order matter/is there precedence in Proguard?

Tags: proguard, android-proguard

In the proguard-rules.pro file, does the order of the statements matter?
For example, more broad to more specific:

```
# Class names are needed in reflection
-keepnames class com.amazonaws.**
-keepnames class com.amazon.**
# This is a big hammer to fix "unable to marshall response" errors.
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.** { *; }
# Request handlers defined in request.handlers
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.**.*Handler
```

versus, more specific to more broad:

```
# This is a big hammer to fix "unable to marshall response" errors.
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.** { *; }
# Request handlers defined in request.handlers
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.**.*Handler
# Class names are needed in reflection
-keepnames class com.amazonaws.**
-keepnames class com.amazon.**
```

Does the order of the -keep statements affect the way Proguard processes the file?

In addition to that, what about when two -keep* directives cover the same class? Which one takes effect, the first declared in the rules file, or the more specific rule?

For example:

```
-keepnames class com.amazonaws.**
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.** { *; }
```

The second rule specifies a subset of the first rule, but the second rule is a more restrictive rule (-keep vs. -keepnames).  Which of those statements will effect the subset of namespace?

Comment: I'd like to know too, did you find out anything in the meantime?

Comment: For the first part, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56272481/does-the-order-of-rules-in-proguard-rules-pro-matter - currently the two answers are a claimed "no" and an implied "yes". Not sure about the order of precedence for overlapping rules though.