# Does the order of rules in proguard-rules.pro matter?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

Does the order of proguard rules has matter or the rules can be written in any order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of rules does not matter. You can write it in any order.

Answer (score 0):

If you removing code via proguard. For example: remove all Log row [How to Remove all debug logging calls before publishing app to Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446248/how-to-remove-all-debug-logging-calls-before-publishing-app-to-google-play)

Proguard will work faster if the deletion occurs at the very beginning.